# subsequences of an array that are not zero

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write code to get the subsequences of a list of this form:

`l = [240,200,160,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]`

Basically, I need to get the subsequences that are not zero, so I need an output in this form:

`output = [[255,200,160,4] , [4,4,4] , [1,1,1,1]]`

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contiguous subsequences?  Paging Dr. Groupby, Dr. [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [240,200,160,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, lambda x: x != 0) if k]
[[240, 200, 160, 4], [4, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

or even if we take advantage of the fact `bool(0)` is `False` and `bool(any other integer)` is `True`:

```
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, bool) if k]
[[240, 200, 160, 4], [4, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: +1 for `Paging Dr. Groupby, Dr. itertools.groupby`

Comment: ... and for using `bool` instead of my ugly `lambda`. Yours certainly is a nicer solution

Answer (score 4):

```
In [117]: l = [240,200,160,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]

In [118]: [list(vals) for mask,vals in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda n:n!=0) if mask]
Out[118]: [[240, 200, 160, 4], [4, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```