# Finding 'runs' within a list

Tags: python, list

I have an array with values like:

```
list1=[0,0,1,1,14,4,3,0,0,0,1,4,3]
```

I want to find the length of runs within that array where x > 0. So the output would be something like:

```
runs = [5,3]
```

This is what I have so far, but don't know how to proceed:

```
runs = []
curr = 0
for x in list1:
    while x > 0:
    curr += 1
#Not sure where to go from here. Somehow append curr to runs and 
reset curr once the run is over
```

Is this the right way to even approach it?

Comment: Is this for a class, where you need to show you can do it "from scratch", as it were, or can you use library functions like `itertools.groupby` (as done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391620/subsequences-of-an-array-that-are-not-zero/19391679#19391679), for example) to simplify the task?

Comment: `while x > 0:` will get you stuck in an infinite loop since x can not change until after the `while` loop is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
runs = []
curr = 0
for x in list1:
    if x == 0:
        if curr != 0: 
            runs.append(curr)
            curr = 0
    else:
        curr = curr + 1
if curr > 0: runs.append(curr)
```

Answer (score 3):

When all you have is an input and an output it's hard to ascertain the answer "is this the right way to approach it?". It depends on what you want answered.  But here is a modification on DSM's suggestion that fits.

```
import itertools as it
l=[0,0,1,1,14,4,3,0,0,0,1,4,3]
[len(list(cgen)) for c,cgen in it.groupby(l, lambda x: x>0) if c]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
runs, c = [], 0
for x in list1 + [0]:
    if x:
        c += 1
    elif c:
        runs.append(c)
        c = 0
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer not using groupby. Nice way to append [0] to ensure the last group doesn't run off the end of the list without getting appended to runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(arr):
  cur=[]
  index1=0
  while index1<len(arr):
    if arr[index1]!=0:
      index2=index1
      while index2!=0 and index2<len(arr):
        index2+=1
      cur.append(index2-index1)
      index1=index2
    else:
      index1+=1
  return cur
```