# How to slice Python list by the occurrences of an item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If given the following list `lst`:

```
import random as rnd, operator as op, itertools as it
from functools import partial

lst = [x for x in it.islice(it.cycle(range(1,10)), 50)]
idx = set(rnd.sample(range(len(lst)), 10))
for i in idx:
    lst.insert(i, 0)
```

How can I slice it by the occurrences of 0?

My current strategy is this:

```
new_lst = [list(g) for k,g in it.groupby(lst, partial(op.eq, 0))]
new_lst
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0],
 [1, 2],
 [0],
 [3, 4],
 [0],
 [5],
 [0],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [0],
 [9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0],
 [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [0],
 [7],
 [0],
 [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Note in the resulting `new_lst` I still have the separators, hence to achieve the *desired result* I have to iterate over once again:

```
new_lst = [i for i in new_lst if 0 not in i]
new_lst
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [7],
 [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a condition on the key, `k`:

```
new_lst = [list(g) for k,g in it.groupby(lst, partial(op.eq, 0)) if not k]
```

Or more direct, using `op.ne`:

```
new_lst = [list(g) for k,g in it.groupby(lst, partial(op.ne, 0)) if k]
```

Or without `partial` (note the space in `0 .__ne__`, or use `(0).__ne__`):

```
new_lst = [list(g) for k,g in it.groupby(lst, 0 .__ne__) if k]
```

Comment: In the particular case when we're splitting by 0, we could use bool: `[list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, bool) if k]`, as done [long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391679/487339)..

Comment: @DSM That's nice, too, but IMHO the intent behind "!= 0" is still a bit clearer. Also, in this question, slicing by `0` might just be an example. Using `eq` or `ne` it more generally applicable.

Comment: That's true enough, but I don't want to hear the word "clear" from someone who just did `0  .__ne__`. ;-)

Comment: @DSM Agreed, the Python syntax is not so pretty is this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this, which uses no libraries:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0]

# indices of all zeroes
indexes = [-1] + [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e == 0]

# get all the sublists
result = []
for start, end in zip(indexes, indexes[1:]):
    result.append(lst[start+1:end])

# add last if any
result.append(lst[end+1:])

# filter out empty lists
print([x for x in result if x])
```

Which Outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```